# File.ReadAllBytes() throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, out-of-memory

I am loading small pdf files into the buffer an getting the OutOfMemoryEception. File Size 220KB works fine, the next size I have tested is 4,50MB an this file throws the exception. What ist the maximum file size and what can I do to change the max size? 4,5MB ist not that much :-)

This is the related code:

```
ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
int i = dataItem.DisplayIndex;
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(Session["pdfFileToSplit"].ToString());
string unique = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
Session[unique] = buffer;

Panel thumbnailPanel = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("thumbnails");
Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
thumbnail.SessionKey = unique;
thumbnail.Index = i+1;
thumbnail.DPI = 17;
thumbnail.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
thumbnailPanel.Controls.Add(thumbnail);
```

Ok I just saw something really mysterios (for me). I uploaded a file below 10MB an whatching the used memory of the IIS Server(w3wp.exe), nothing dramatic happens, a few MB up, a few down, everything worked fine. Than I've tried the same thing with a 12MB file. At the beginning it appears same, but than, suddenly, out of nowhere, the used memory of the w3wp.exe exploded to 1,5GB an than the server crashes....

Comment: I'm using a Component that requires to keep the file in the session  http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfthumbnail.aspx

Comment: I don't know this component. Either way, the session state is not build to keep a large amount of data. You should reconsider writing the thumbnails to temp files, and only keep the path to these files in the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OutOfMemoryException is on server side or client side?

When you useSession[unique] = buffer, you're storing all the files (represented as byte arrays) simultaneously in your session.

That can be a lot of information.

If your session is "InProc", your server will probably run out of memory.

The limit is the memory of the machine.

When your request finishes the memory stays allocated in the session. That's the problem. You should set Session[unique] = null if this isn't the desired behavior, making the session dispose the memory on the server. If you put 10 files, 10 will be simultaneously stored in the session even after the requests finishes. They will be disposed only when the session ends.

Comment: I'm using TallComponent.pdf.thumbnail and it's neccessary to store it in the session because there is no other way afaik. 

The exception is server side, but both sides, client and server, has really enough memory to handle 4,5MB

Comment: I've edited the answer, complementing your question. I know that this is the behavior of the component, but the behavior of the session is the one I've described. If you put a hundred files this way, all of them will be stored in memory (in server memory).

Comment: Ok, thanks, 4,5MB works fine now but >10MB still throws the exception. Maybe there are any limits on the Visual Studio asp.net development server?

Comment: Can you check, in your task manager how much memory is allocated for VS DEV server and your state server (aspnet_state.exe)? You can consider using another way of storing the session values (like database, for example) if you don't want to change your architecture (I'do go through this path). The process that probably is consuming a lot of memory is aspnet_state.exe.

Comment: WebDev Server is currently at at 107,7MB. aspnet_state.exe is not running.

Comment: What is your state server configuration in ASP.NET? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok I just saw something really mysterios (for me). I uploaded a file below 10MB an whatching the used memory of the IIS Server(w3wp.exe), nothing dramatic happens, a few MB up, a few down, everything worked fine. Than I've tried the same thing with a 12MB file. At the beginning it appears same, but than, suddenly, out of nowhere, the used memory of the w3wp.exe exploded to 1,5GB an than the server crashes....